# Finding various substrings in NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring

I have an NSString and am attempting to find the first location of either of three strings @"aaa" and @"bbb" and @"ccc".

```
range = [text rangeOfString:@"aaa" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(rangeStart, rangeLength)];
```

Is there any simple way to add a logical operator (or) to the `rangeOfString:` method? I tried `rangeOfString:(@"aaa" || @"bbb" || @"ccc")` but it threw an exception. Or is there a simple workaround. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Regular Expression

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(aaa|bbb|ccc)" options:0 error:NULL];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])];
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

```
[[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern: @"(aaa|bbb|ccc)" options: NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error: &error] rangeOfFirstMatchInString: text options: 0 range: NSMakeRange(rangeStart, rangeLength)]
```